# Obtener cadena con comillas

Tags: php

devs, tengo un problema intentando separar una cadena con php, la cual esta ejemplificada de la siguiente forma:

```
Esta es una cadena de prueba* "este es bloque entre comillas* es un bloque de varias líneas* en este caso son tres"* fin de la cadena
```

Y lo que quiero obtener es lo siguiente:

```
Esta es una cadena de prueba*

"este es bloque entre comillas* 
es un bloque de varias líneas* 
en este caso son tres"*

fin de la cadena.
```

Les menciono que los asteriscos son saltos de línea por lo que hacer un explode con el asterisco como delimitador no me funciona y me interesa obtener la parte entre comillas separada del resto para poder aplicar un estilo diferente.

¿Me podrían apoyar con alguna idea? Hasta ahora tengo esto, pero el segundo explode es el problema porque aunque separa el texto por las comillas lo deja sin ellas y no puedo identificarlo para darle un estilo diferente.

```php
echo $texto_original = 'Esta es una cadena de prueba* "este es bloque entre comillas* es un bloque de varias líneas* en este caso son tres"* fin de la cadena';

echo "<br><br>";

//Primer explode para convertir los asteriscos en saltos de linea
echo $texto_lineas = str_replace('*', '<br>', $texto_original);

echo "<br><br>";

//Segundo explode para obtener el texto entre comillas
$texto_separado = explode('"', $texto_lineas);
$i = 0;
while ($texto_separado[$i]) {
  echo $texto_separado[$i];
  echo "<br>";
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Buen día, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado hacer ya que en este sitio no resolvemos tareas/proyectos, para cada pregunta es necesario que el autor muestre un esfuerzo por resolver su problema. Saludos!

Comment: Lo siento, muchas gracias por tu observación :)

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo que podrías hacer es utilizar [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php) junto con un `regex`:

```
echo $texto_original = 'Esta es una cadena de prueba* "este es bloque entre comillas* es un bloque de varias líneas* en este caso son tres"* fin de la cadena';

// Separar con preg_split y un regex
$partes = preg_split('@(?<=\*)@', $texto_original);
var_dump($partes);
```

El [`regex`](https://maugelves.com/expresiones-regulares-en-php/) de pasado positivo `@(?<=\*)@` encuentra los asteriscos y divide después de encontrarlos.

Debes tener en cuenta que en tu `string` tienes espacios después de los asterizcos por lo que esos espacios se verán reflejados en la respuesta. Otro punto importante es que al tener comillas en el texto y generar un arreglo de `string` las comillas originales van a ocacionar problemas, deberías escaparlas de esta forma `\"`.

El código anterior devuelve lo siguiente:

```
Esta es una cadena de prueba* "este es bloque entre comillas* es un bloque de varias líneas* en este caso son tres"* fin de la cadena<br><br>Esta es una cadena de prueba<br> "este es bloque entre comillas<br> es un bloque de varias líneas<br> en este caso son tres"<br> fin de la cadena<br><br>

array(5) {
  [0]=>  string(29) "Esta es una cadena de prueba*"
  [1]=>  string(32) " "este es bloque entre comillas*"
  [2]=>  string(32) " es un bloque de varias líneas*"
  [3]=>  string(24) " en este caso son tres"*"
  [4]=>  string(17) " fin de la cadena"
}
```

**Información adicional:** Te recomiendo utilizar la página [`regex101`](https://regex101.com/) cuando necesites trabajar con `regex` ya que te permite probarlo y además del lado derecho te muestra una explicación de las diferentes partes del `regex` que estás utilizando.